# Kernel of the map $D^2+aD+b : k[[X]] \to k[[X]]$ , where $D :k[[X]] \to k[[X]]$ is the usual derivative map

Tags: commutative-algebra, field-theory, power-series, linear-transformations, valuation-theory

Let $k$ be a field . Let $P(X) \in  k[X]$ be a monic polynomial of degree $2$ which is not a perfect square in $ \bar k[X]$ i.e. $P(X)$ has no repeated roots in $\bar k$ , where $\bar k$ denotes the algebraic closure of $k$.

Let $D : k[[X]] \to k[[X]]$ be the usual derivation map i.e. $D (\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nX^n)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n a_n X^{n-1}$ . So then $P(D) : k[[X]] \to k[[X]]$ is also a $k$-linear map. Can we explicitly determine $\ker P(D)$ ?

Here $k[[X]]$ denotes the power series ring in one variable over $k$.

If it is helpful, you may assume $[\bar k : k] \le 2$

Comment: you just solve the ODE $P(D)f=0$ in the standard way (a linear combination of exponentials or of sin's and cos's) - that gives you the solutions also in $\mathbb R[[X]]$

Comment: @user8268: Sorry but I don't want to use analysis.

Comment: there is nothing analytic about it: you're looking for solutions of $(D-s)(D-t)f=0$, where $s,t$ are the roots of $P$ (they may be in a quadratic extension of $k$, but for the moment let's work with  $f$'s with coeffs in that extension); the solutions are $f=g+h$ where $(D-s)g=0$ and $(D-t)h=0$ (just linear algebra so far), and you'll find easily all the solutions $g$ and $h$. If $s,t$ are not in $k$, choose the linear combination so that you get coefficients in $k$. But in the end it's just the formal power series $e^{sX}$, $e^{tX}$.

Comment: @user8268 : and how did you decompose $f$ into $g$ and $h$ ?

Comment: $1=(D-s)/(t-s)+(D-t)/(s-t)$, so $g=((D-t)/(s-t)) f$ and $h=((D-s)/(t-s)) f$ (on the kernel of $P(D)$ the operator $D$ has eigenvalues $s,t$, and this is how one gets the projectors to the eigenspaces - just linear algebra)

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to solve the differential equation 
$$\frac{d^2 y}{d x^2} + a \frac{d y}{d x} + b = 0,$$ which, on the level of power series is

$$n (n-1) a_n + a (n-1) a_{n-1 }+ b a_{n-2} = 0,$$ for $n \geq 2.$

Otherwise, if the roots of $P$ are real, this will be a linear combination of two exponentials, otherwise of sines and cosines.

Comment: Sorry but I don't want to use analysis.

Comment: @misao suit yourself. However, downvoting an answer because you "don't want to use analysis" is obnoxious and a good way to get shunned.

Comment: Dear Igor, I upvoted your answer and your comment. Having noticed this user's behavior a few days ago, I decided to avoid interacting with them. In the present case, they (1) asked a question, (2) got 2 correct answers, (3) downvoted them on the ground that they used analysis, which isn't true (and the question didn't prohibit analysis), (4) changed the question.

Comment: Dear @Pierre-YvesGaillard Thanks! For those of us who spend a lot of time answering questions this sort of obnoxiousness is a bit upsetting.

Answer (score 1):

Answer not using analysis.
We look for formal series solutions of $P(D)y(x)=0$ in the form $y(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{c_n}{n!} x^n$ where $n!=1\cdot2\cdot...\cdot n$. Then $Dy(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{c_{n+1}}{n!} x^n$. The equation $P(D)y(x)=0$ is satisfied if and only if $c_{n+2}+a\,c_{n+1}+b\,c_{n}=0$ for all nonegative integers $n$.
The solution sequences of this ''recurrence'' equation are determined by their ''initial'' terms $c_0,c_1$. Hence they form a vector space of dimension 2.
It is more convenient to express them in a different basis:
If $t^2+at+b=0$ has two roots $r,s$ in $k$, then use the sequences
$r^n, n\geq0$ and $s^n, n\geq0$. If $t^2+at+b=0$ has no roots in $k$, then it has two conjugate roots $r,\bar r$ in $\bar k$. A basis in $k[[x]]$ is then given by the sequences $r^n+\bar r^n, n\geq0$  and $r^{n+1}+\bar r^{n+1}, n\geq0$.  Here I use one assumption in the form that $\bar k=k[q]$, where $q^2\in k$ and therefore elements $f$ of $\bar k$ satisfying $\bar f=f$ are in $k$. I also used the assumption that there are no double roots of $t^2+at+b=0$.
Without wanting to use any analysis, let me indicate that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{r^n}{n!}x^n$ is the power series of an exponential function.